JWT Auth issue While integrating gcp function in API gateway
I have created a gcp function and deployed it. Everything is working fine from function url. I have integrated api gateway and accessing the same api from api gateway url but getting below issue
JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm
    at /workspace/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:145:19
    at getSecret (/workspace/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:97:14)
    at module.exports [as verify] (/workspace/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:101:10)
    at authenticateToken (/workspace/middlewares/chat-gpt-auth.middleware.js:29:9)

i have default jwt algorithm at both create and verify time. below is my api gateway config file
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: ChatGPT API
  description: API Gateway for ChatGPT Function
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /openai:
    post:
      summary: Handle ChatGPT requests
      description: This endpoint handles POST requests for ChatGPT via Google Cloud Function.
      operationId: handleChatGPTRequest
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: Authorization
          required: true
          type: string
          description: Bearer token for authorization.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '405':
          description: Method Not Allowed
        '500':
          description: Internal Server Error
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://gcp-function-url/openai
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      x-google-extensions:
        securityDefinitions:
          Bearer:
            type: apiKey
            name: Authorization
            in: header
        security:
          - Bearer: []

securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header

security:
  - Bearer: []

I tried by defining verification jwt algorithm but did not found any solution

I encourage you to review Authentication between services
